# Preventing child prop update if parent component unmounts

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

After upgrading to the latest react-redux (v7), I'm having issues with prop updates. Here's an example:

```
const shouldRender = WrappedComponent => props => props.shouldRender ? <WrappedComponent {...props} /> : null

const MyComponent = compose(
  connect(state => ({ shouldRender: Boolean(state.page) })),
  shouldRender,
  connect(state => ({ title: state.page.title }))
)(MyBaseComponent)

<MyComponent />

store.dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR_STATE' }) // => Sets state.page to null
```

In v5 of react-redux, when state.page is reseted to it's initial state (null), the `shouldRender` HOC will render null instead of the component and thus not try to get the state.page.title in the next line.

After upgrading to v7, the same scenario still triggers `state.page.title` and throw a error (cannot get title of undefined).

The most simple solution would be to not rely on a parent HOC and guard the props (`title: state.page && state.page.title` but this will introduce loads of guards everywhere in my code.

How can I prevent the last connect mapStateToProps from happening if the parent already unmounts (thus prop change on children is not needed as it will get unmounted anyway).

Comment: If you are using `compose` from `redux`, it composes functions from right to left. Have you tried reversing the order ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by upgrading to 7.0.3